# JavaScript Object is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I am making a small program for myself on a video game. The issue is that it reads certain objects as not defined when it says the errors in the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //A roster for all character choices.
        var roster = {
            Riven:{name: "Riven", rival: Jax, rival2: Pantheon}, 
            Pantheon:{name: "Pantheon", rival: Olaf, rival2: Darius},
            Veigar:{name: "Veigar", rival: Akali, rival2: Fizz},
            Olaf:{name: "Olaf", rival: Kayle, rival2: Kennen},
            Jax:{name: "Jax", rival: Malphite, rival2: Pantheon},
            Akali:{name: "Akali", rival: Garen, rival2: LeeSin},
            Malphite:{}, 
            Darius:{}, 
            LeeSin:{}, 
            Garen:{}, 
            Kayle:{},
            Fizz:{},
        };
```

It says the object Darius is not defined in Pantheon's object or any time I reference Darius after this block of code. However, the Olaf, Akali, and anyone that had the full object property list are defined. I tried putting in those properties in the objects being read as not defined, but that does not work. I'm new to JavaScript, and I have no clue what to do. If it is relevant, I am calling jQuery library in the script just before this in my HTML code.

Comment: Might be you are not closing document ready function }).

Comment: object property keys are not variables. You can create arbitrarily named properties any time, but you can't use that property name as a variable the way you are doing in your nested objects

Comment: just a small point - why is Jax not one of Pantheon's rivals?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No reason. Was just trying to get the code to work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl mentions in a comment, you haven't defined a variable named `Jax`. After `roster` is defined, you can reference `roster.Jax`, but you cannot reference it before you have finished defining the object because until then `roster` is still undefined.

You will have to do this:

```
    var roster = {
        Riven:{name: "Riven"}, 
        Pantheon:{name: "Pantheon"},
        Veigar:{name: "Veigar"},
        Olaf:{name: "Olaf"},
        Jax:{name: "Jax"},
        Akali:{name: "Akali"},
        Malphite:{}, 
        Darius:{}, 
        LeeSin:{}, 
        Garen:{}, 
        Kayle:{},
        Fizz:{},
    };
```

And then assign the rivals like this:

```
roster.Riven.rival = roster.Jax;
```

---

That would be a mess, so I would start with an array like the following. (Notice how the `rival` and `rival2` properties are just the names (strings) at this point.)

```
var characters = [
    { name: 'Riven', rival: 'Jax', rival2: 'Pantheon' },
    { name: 'Pantheon', rival: 'Olaf', rival2: 'Darius' },
    { name: 'Veigar', rival: 'Akali', rival2: 'Fizz' },
    { name: 'Olaf', rival: 'Kayle', rival2: 'Kennen' },
    { name: 'Jax', rival: 'Malphite', rival2: 'Pantheon' },
    { name: 'Akali', rival: 'Garen', rival2: 'LeeSin' },
    { name: 'Malphite' },
    { name: 'Darius' },
    { name: 'LeeSin' },
    { name: 'Garen' },
    { name: 'Kayle' },
    { name: 'Fizz' }
];
```

You can then create the roster object from the array by doing the following. (The `rival` and `rival2` properties are still just the names (strings) at this point.)

```
var roster = {};
characters.forEach(function(character) {
    roster[character.name] = character;
});
```

If you really want the `rival` and `rival2` properties to be object references instead of just the names, you could convert them with the following code.

```
characters.forEach(function(character) {
    character.rival = roster[character.rival];
    character.rival2 = roster[character.rival2];
});
```

---

And if you want to support more than two rivals: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r73be20k/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you split your object's declaration:

```
// here is an empty or a default setting, just to avoid
// an undefined exception
var roster = {
            Malphite:{}, 
            Darius:{}, 
            LeeSin:{}, 
            Garen:{}, 
            Kayle:{},
            Fizz:{},
        };
```

and then the other properties:

```
// here's the real declaration
roster = {
            Riven:{name: "Riven", rival: roster.Jax, rival2: roster.Pantheon}, 
            Pantheon:{name: "Pantheon", rival: roster.Olaf, rival2: roster.Darius},
            Veigar:{name: "Veigar", rival: roster.Akali, rival2: roster.Fizz},
            Olaf:{name: "Olaf", rival: roster.Kayle, rival2: roster.Kennen},
            Jax:{name: "Jax", rival: roster.Malphite, rival2: roster.Pantheon},
            Akali:{name: "Akali", rival: roster.Garen, rival2: roster.LeeSin},
            Malphite:{}, 
            Darius:{}, 
            LeeSin:{}, 
            Garen:{}, 
            Kayle:{},
            Fizz:{},
        };
```

note the `roster.` prefix before accesing the object's properties